# Is there an alternative to Java.perform(function(){...}) in Frida?

Tags: javascript, android, frida

Using Frida, I've got the following JavaScript:

```
setImmediate(function() {
    console.log("[*] Hello!");

    if (Java.available) {
        console.log("[*] Java is available...");

        Java.perform(function () {
            console.log("[*] Here we go!");

            var aClass = Java.use("x.package.path.aClass");
            aClass.aMethod.implementation = function(arg1) {
                console.log("x.package.path.aClass.aMethod() is hooked!");
                ...
            };

            var bClass = Java.use("y.package.path.bClass");
            bClass.bMethod.implementation = function(arg1, arg2) {
                console.log("y.package.path.bClass.bMethod() is hooked!");
                ...
            };
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("[*] Java isn't available!!!");
    }
});
```

Then there is only one chance to hook those methods. It does rarely and barely hook at least one of them. Does it need some time to hook after a class/object is loaded?

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: setImmediate will have no effect. You probably need to attach your app earlier, before these methods are called. A way to do it is to spawn the app yourself (e.g. https://awakened1712.github.io/hacking/hacking-frida/).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin With that it spawns the app but hooks anything. Initially I did combine Frida with JDB and I did attach Frida before the method call.

Comment: are you trying to hook JNI calls ? please append method signature for each method